# Count values using groupby function and using apply function at the same time

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I'm trying to count the occurance of grouped values and write values in a column using apply and grouby function on a dataframe. I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': ['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name4', 'name2', 'name5', 'name5'], 'colB': ['red', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']})
```

I have two statements which gives me the correct result, but I need the result in combination. One is:

```
df_new = df.groupby("colA").count()
```

which gives

```
colA
name1    1
name2    3
name4    1
name5    2
```

the other one is

```
df_new = df.groupby("colA")["colB"].apply(lambda lists: ','.join(color)).reset_index(name='Color')
```

and gives

```
    colA                Color
0  name1                   red
1  name2  yellow,yellow,yellow
2  name4                 black
3  name5            green,blue
```

what I need is the combination looking like

```
    colA                Color      Count grouped A
0  name1                   red     1
1  name2  yellow,yellow,yellow     3
2  name4                 black     1
3  name5            green,blue     2
```

Trying to combinate in many ways and of course did research but I couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join first to second as new column and use `colA` to assign values in correct places.

```
df_new = df_2.join(df_1, on='colA')
```

It needed also `df_1.rename(columns={'colB': 'Count grouped A'})`

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': ['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name4', 'name2', 'name5', 'name5'], 'colB': ['red', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']})

df_1 = df.groupby("colA").count().rename(columns={'colB': 'Count grouped A'})

df_2 = df.groupby("colA")["colB"].apply(lambda lists: ','.join(lists)).reset_index(name='Color')

df_new = df_2.join(df_1, on='colA')

print(df_new)
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same with small changes

- first `groups = df.groupby("colA")` and later two times `groups...`
- `.apply(','.join)` instead of `.apply(lambda lists: ','.join(lists))`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': ['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name4', 'name2', 'name5', 'name5'], 'colB': ['red', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']})

groups = df.groupby("colA")

df_1 = groups.count().rename(columns={'colB': 'Count grouped A'})
df_2 = groups["colB"].apply(','.join).reset_index(name='Color')

df_new = df_2.join(df_1, on='colA')

print(df_new)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you would keep `Color` as `list` then it could be simpler.

You could use `.str.len()` to count elements in `list`

`.str` suggests that it has functions for strings but some of them work also with `list` (ie. `.str[1:4]`) or even with `dictionary` (ie. `.str[key]`)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': ['name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name4', 'name2', 'name5', 'name5'], 'colB': ['red', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'black', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue']})

df_new = df.groupby("colA")["colB"].apply(list).reset_index(name='Color')
df_new['Count grouped A'] = df_new['Color'].str.len()

print(df_new)
```